# Using flask-jwt-extended callbacks with flask-restful and create_app

Tags: python, flask, jwt, flask-restful, flask-jwt-extended

I'm trying to create API tokens for my flask API with flask-jwt-extended. I'm trying to initialize the [token_in_blacklist_loader](http://flask-jwt-extended.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#flask_jwt_extended.JWTManager.token_in_blacklist_loader) but can't figure out the right way to do that.

The problem is that `token_in_blacklist_loader` is implemented as a decorator. It is supposed to be used in the following way:

```
@jwt.token_in_blacklist_loader
def check_if_token_in_blacklist(decrypted_token):
    jti = decrypted_token['jti']
    return jti in blacklist
```

^ [from the docs here](http://flask-jwt-extended.readthedocs.io/en/latest/blacklist_and_token_revoking.html)

Where `jwt` is defined as:

```
jwt = JWTManager(app)
```

But if using the `create_app` pattern, then `jwt` variable is hidden inside a function, and cannot be used in the global scope for decorators.

What is the right way to fix this / work around this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I ended up doing was putting the handler inside of `create_app` like so:

```
def create_app(name: str, settings_override: dict = {}):
    app = Flask(name, ...)
    ...
    jwt = JWTManager(app)
    @jwt.token_in_blacklist_loader
    def check_token_in_blacklist(token_dict: dict) -> bool:
        ...
```

Answer (score 2):

Put the `JWTManager` in a different file, and initialize it with the `jwt.init_app` function

As an example, see:

https://github.com/vimalloc/flask-jwt-extended/blob/master/examples/database_blacklist/extensions.py

and

https://github.com/vimalloc/flask-jwt-extended/blob/master/examples/database_blacklist/app.py

Comment: If you add a code snippet to the answer I'll accept. I'm not sure how jwt=... is initialized in the extensions file though

Comment: Those links are part of a full working code sample which you can see how this works. You can also check out this link http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/patterns/appfactories/ for more documentation on how this concept works.

Comment: And to clarify, it is not initialized in the extensions file, it is initialized in the create_app() function.

Comment: Unfortunately both links in this answer are now dead